# Why do people recommend putting my text inside strings?

Tags: android, textview

Why do people recommend putting my text inside strings? Example:

Should I use:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_text_in_strings" />
```

Instead of:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Text" />
```

?

There is any reason for that? Is that critical? How badly does this affect performances?

Android Studio Note: `Hardcodedstring "Repeat", should use @string resource`

Comment: `Critical`? No, it's not. `Best practice`? Yes, it is. You can always change your strings without editing the code and, as @tyczj points out, it's great for localization. `Next step`: accept his answer in order to remove the question from the *Unanswered Question Queue*.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is recommended to use string resources instead of normal string is for localization. You can have the same string resource id but for multiple languages.

If you don't care about localization then it really does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

string.xml(ko)

string name="my_text_in_strings">안녕</string

string.xml(en)

string name="my_text_in_strings">Hello</string

This method is used to apply localization using the same ID.